# Pixi.js text moves up and down when scale and resolution is used

Tags: javascript, text, font-size, pixi.js

I am rendering text using Pixi.js. The text I am rendering is inside a container with a scale, so I have to reduce the font size to account for the scale.

```
const app = new PIXI.Application({ background: '#1099bb' });

document.body.appendChild(app.view);

const fontSize = 40;
const scale = 4

const text = new PIXI.Text(
    'Scaled',
    new PIXI.TextStyle({ fontSize: fontSize / scale })
);

const container = new PIXI.Container();
container.scale.set(scale);
container.addChild(text);
app.stage.addChild(container);
```

Because of the scale, the text gets blury since Pixi renders it with a smaller font size and then upscales it. This can be fixed with one line of code, setting a resolution to match the scale:

```
text.resolution = scale;
```

Now the text looks sharp. However, there is still a problem. When I animate the font size, I notice that the text jumps around slightly in the vertical direction, as can be seen in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/owdpvzrc/). There appears to be some kind of rounding issue going on.

How can I get rid of this "jumpiness", and have the text be correctly positioned?